# nGram autocomplete result with boolean query (ElasticSearch)

Tags: elasticsearch, autocomplete

I have implemented multifield partial autocomplete using nGram-s as presented in the following blogpost: https://qbox.io/blog/multi-field-partial-word-autocomplete-in-elasticsearch-using-ngrams1
It works great in case of a single match query. However, it fails when using the same match query inside a boolean query which contains several other queries as well.
Is there any way to gain the same result as a single match query provides in case of a boolean query?

For instance the match query below works as expected. It retrieves all those documents which contain both "shop" and "mi".

```
{
     "query": {
         "match" : {
            "_all": {
                 "query": "shop mi",
                 "operator": "and"
            }
         }
     }
 }
```

Here is a sample document, that is retrieved by the query above:

```
{
          "message" : "An error occurred while executing doInBackground()",
          "@version" : "1",
          "@timestamp" : "2018-01-23T10:22:46.689Z",
          "type" : "mytype",
          "app_name" : "name",
          "app_package" : "com.package",
          "exception" : "java.lang.RuntimeException",
          "is_handled" : false,
          "jailbroken" : false,
          "language_code" : "in",
          "orientation" : 0,
          "os_version" : "7.1.2",
          "phone_manufacturer" : "Xiaomi",
          "phone_model" : "Mi A1",
          "platform" : "android",
          "proc_info" : 8,
          "recommended_mgpx" : 5,
          "sd_card_available" : true,
          "stacktrace" : "java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()\n\tat android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:325)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)\nCaused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cannot parse package /storage/emulated/0/app/.downloads/.shop/package\n\tat java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)\n\t... 3 more\n",
          "total_disk_space" : 3071504384,
          "total_memory" : 3769253888,
          "user_id" : "81257074",
          "crash_case" : "at com.package.util.ae.a(ProGuard:43)"
        }
```

In the fields "phone_manufacturer" and "phone_model" you can see the "mi" that had to be inside the document. And the field "stacktrace" you can see the "shop"(listed as a directory) that had to be in the document along with the "mi", for the document to match.

Whereas the boolean query below, which contains the same match query doesn't retrieve any documents. It results in 0 hits. However, it should also retrieve all those documents, which contain both "shop" and "mi", but having values for the "@timestamp" field in the specified range. In case of the document above, the value of the field "@timestamp" is in the required range. Hence, it should also be inside the hits of the second query.

```
{
"query": {
  "bool" : {
    "must" : [
      {
        "range" : {
          "@timestamp" : {
            "from" : 1516881600000,
            "to" : 1516882500000,
            "include_lower" : true,
            "include_upper" : true,
            "format" : "epoch_millis",
            "boost" : 1.0
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "filter" : [
      {
        "match" : {
          "_all" : {
            "query" : "shop mi",
            "operator" : "and",
            "boost" : 1.0
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "boost" : 1.0
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you show one document that you expect to match but doesn't?

Comment: This was got by the match query, but boolean query gives 0 hits. In the "stacktrace" you can see the "shop".

{
          "message" : "An error occurred while executing doInBackground()",
          "@version" : "1",
          "@timestamp" : "2018-01-23T10:23:21.826Z",
          "stacktrace" : "java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cannot parse package /storage/emulated/0/some/.downloads/.shop/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)\n\t... 3 more\n",
          "crash_case" : "at com.this.case.ae.a(ProGuard:43)"
        }

Comment: update your question with a properly formatted document.

Comment: Thanks for the note. Now you can check out the updated version.

Comment: That cannot match because 1516881600000 is on January 25th

Comment: Yes, you're right. After changing the ranges properly, the boolean query also returned the same document. Thanks.